# MKMapView in SpriteKit - Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, mkmapview, skscene

I'm using a MKMapView in an SKScene but it is not displaying. Here's my code.

```
    import SpriteKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

    class Map : SKScene, MKMapViewDelegate {

 var startY: CGFloat = 0.0
    var lastY: CGFloat = 0.0
    var moveableArea = SKNode()
        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

// set position & add scrolling/moveable node to screen
        moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
        self.addChild(moveableArea)
        //moveableArea.addChild(Node Here)
            var map : MKMapView! = MKMapView()
            map.delegate = self

            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5031135, -6.572772100000066)
            map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5031135, -6.572772100000066), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)), animated: true)

            var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            annotation.title = "This is my Town!"
            annotation.subtitle = "Enniscorthy, Co. Wexford"
            map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            map.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)              
            map.center = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.width / 2)
            view.addSubview(map)
        }

 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)



            startY = location.y
            lastY = location.y


            let tappednode = atPoint(location)
            let tappedNodeName: String? = tappednode.name


            if tappedNodeName == "exit" {
                if let view = self.view {

                    let scene = MenuGame(size: self.size)
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                    view.presentScene(scene)
                }
            }
        }



    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {




        for touch in touches {
        let location = (touch as AnyObject).location(in: self)
        // set the new location of touch
        var currentY = location.y

        // Set Top and Bottom scroll distances, measured in screenlengths
        var topLimit:CGFloat = 0.0
        var bottomLimit:CGFloat = 0.6

        // Set scrolling speed - Higher number is faster speed
        var scrollSpeed:CGFloat = 1.0

        // calculate distance moved since last touch registered and add it to current position
        var newY = moveableArea.position.y + ((currentY - lastY)*scrollSpeed)

        // perform checks to see if new position will be over the limits, otherwise set as new position
        if newY < self.size.height*(-topLimit) {
            moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: moveableArea.position.x, y: self.size.height*(-topLimit))
        }
        else if newY > self.size.height*bottomLimit {
            moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: moveableArea.position.x, y: self.size.height*bottomLimit)
        }
        else {
            moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: moveableArea.position.x, y: newY)
        }

        // Set new last location for next time
        lastY = currentY
    }

    }

    }
```

There is no tutorials on how to do this in SpriteKit so much of this is guesswork. What am I missing?

Update1: How should I add the MKMapView to the MoveableArea?

Answer (score 0):

```
        let map : MKMapView! = MKMapView()
        map.delegate = self
   // below line is missing  
   map.frame=CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.size.width,height: self.size.width);
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5031135, -6.572772100000066)
        map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5031135, -6.572772100000066), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)), animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)
        annotation.title = "This is my Town!"
        annotation.subtitle = "Enniscorthy, Co. Wexford"
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        map.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
        map.center = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.width / 2)
        view.addSubview(map)

you missed frame of your map view
```

Comment: Works perfect! I have one problem, I use a sort of touches Moved as scrollview in this SKScene. (Full code in the update) All of my SkSpriteNode() and SKLabelNodes() are added with moveArea.addChild(---). What should I do to add this?